# ISO 2017 Shortlist (A1)

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inequality, polynomials

Let $a_i$ be positive integers for each $i=1$, $2$, $\dots$, $n$. Let $k$ and $M$ be positive integers such that
$$k = \sum_{i=1}^n{1\over a_i}, \quad M = \prod_{i=1}^n a_i$$
If $M > 1$, prove that the polynomial $P(x) = M(x+1)^k - \prod_{i=1}^n (x+a_i)$ has no positive roots.

---

I'm trying to apply the AM-GM inequality to show that $\prod_{i=1}^n (x+a_i) > M(x+1)^k$ for all $x > 0$, hence $P(x) \neq 0$ for all $x > 0$.
But I'm having difficulty with that result.

Since $a_i$ is a positive integer for each $i$, then
$${1\over n}\sum_{i=1}^n a_i \geq \bigg(\prod_{i=1}^n a_i\bigg)^{1/n}$$
with equality iff $a_1 = a_2 = \dots = a_n = T$, so in this case
$M = \prod T = T^n$ and $k = \sum {1\over T} = {n\over T}$. Then
$$P(x) = T^n(x+1)^{n/T} - (x + T)^n$$
Given that $M = T^n > 1$, then $T> 1$ and
$$(x+1)^n < (x+T)^n \implies (x+1)^{n/T}<(x+T)^n$$
But I'm not quite able to show that $T^n(x+1)^{n/T} < (x+T)^n$

EDIT: If I use Bernouli's inequality to conclude $a_i = 1$ for each $i$, is it valid to substitute $T= 1$ into the formula above and conclude that $P(x) = (x+1)^n - (x+T)^n$?

Comment: this is Imo shortlist problem

Comment: i think some algebra section

Comment: @HappieHappieHappie Oops you're right, I'll correct it.

Comment: Yeah ,  i have done the problem then in 2018 after the shortlish realise and its 3 pages word type solution and similar to 2nd solution of shortlist then i saw solution 1 which much shorter,  and what i could remember you idea is nearly correct for sure dear  @Dee.

Comment: i have a website then called scioin.com there i upload that solution many days before but that website was no more because i didn't renew as it has less visitors or traffic.

Answer (score 4):

I think you used AM-GM for an incorrect choice of numbers. The point is, nowhere in your AM-GM is the variable $x$ involved. Secondly, you take the polynomial corresponding to the equality case (when all the $a_i$ are equal) and wish to compare this polynomial pointwise to the case when all the $a_i$ are not equal. Unfortunately, I'm not sure that this comparison is all that easy to prove, although it is possible to prove that the polynomial made up by the equality case is positive for $x>0$.

However, it's easy to correct this. The idea is the following : how would I argue this if there were only one value $a_1$? Perhaps I can build from that one case?

---

In there's only one $a_i$, say $a_1$, then you want to prove that $$
a_1(x+1)^{\frac 1{a_1}} < (x+a_1)
$$
for all values of $x$ (the choice of $<$ is motivated by testing values of $x$ and $a_1$, and realizing that if $P(x)$ never attains zero then it must be either positive or negative throughout).

To solve this, note that as written, there is the potential to execute an AM-GM argument. Indeed, write this as $$
a_1(x+1)^{\frac 1{a_1}} < (x+a_1) \iff (x+1)^{\frac 1{a_1}} < \frac{x+a_1}{a_1} = \frac{(x+1)+\underbrace{1+\ldots+1}_{a_1-1 \text{ times}}}{a_1}
$$

The RHS is the AM of the numbers $(x+1),\underbrace{1,\ldots,1}_{a_1-1 \text{ times}}$, while the LHS is their GM. Thus, the final inequality is a consequence of the AM-GM inequality (and attains equality at $x=0$).

---

However, the general case is not really obvious : you just need to iterate this estimate. Indeed, write the estimate for each $a_i$ :$$
a_1(x+1)^{\frac 1{a_i}} < (x+a_1) \\
a_2(x+1)^{\frac 1{a_2}} < (x+a_2) \\
\vdots \\
a_n(x+1)^{\frac 1{a_n}} < (x+a_n) \\
$$
Just multiplying them together leads to $$
M(x+1)^{k} < \prod_{i=1}^n (x+a_i) , x>0
$$
with equality being attained at $x=0$.

Perhaps the lesson here is that when it's unclear as to how to work with multiple $a_i$, try one $a_1$, see how it works out, and then see if the same method extends. In this case, the extension is too obvious, but even in other cases one can perhaps prosper via an induction argument to finish.